# Vertical align multiple lines break out

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically align the text in my links like this :

[image: what i want]

The whole block are links, and they are all the same size. I tried to set the line-height to the height of the container to center it and then reset the line-height with a span with a defined line-height inside the link but it didn't work  :

[image: what I get]

Here's my code :

```
                    <section class="faq">
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="nav nav--stacked">
                                <li><a href=""><span>où est la bulle à verre la plus proche ?</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><span>quand sont les ramassages ?</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><span>x</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><span>x</span></a></li>
                                <li><a href=""><span>x</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </section>
```

and the css:

```
.faq a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 13px; }

.faq a span {
  line-height: 1.7; }
```

Tried the "table-cell" way, but I didn't get it to work. Also, if any of you have a cleaner solution, it would be awesome and very much appreciated !

[Live version here](http://aurelieremia.be/bruxelles-proprete-final/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this change:

```
.faq a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    /*line-height: 100px;*/ <---- remove
    padding-left: 90px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #bdbdbd;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*margin-bottom: 10px;*/ <--- delete
    font-size: 13px;
}

.nav--stacked > li {
    display: list-item;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.nav--stacked > li > a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 237px;
}
```

Comment: It works, but the problem was that I wanted each link to be the exact same height though.

Comment: Ah ok, added changes - have a look and see if it's what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Delete or decrease your `.faq a` padding. Also this code `line-height` effect it. And include `background-image:` for your image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to try and address all of your issues, here how I would have wrote it. Let me know if it works for you.

HTML:

```
 <nav class="faq">
     <ul class="nav nav--stacked">
         <li><a href="">où est la bulle à verre la plus proche ?</a></li>
         <li><a href="">quand sont les ramassages ?</a></li>
         <li><a href="">x</a></li>
         <li><a href="">x</a></li>
         <li><a href="">x</a></li>
     </ul>
 </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.faq ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.faq li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 90px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    color: #bdbdbd;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.faq li:hover {
    background: #d9dfdc;
    color: #fff;
}
.faq li a {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.faq li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zp238/2/

Comment: Hey ! No problem, I fixed it. I checked your code, and the problem is that the whole block isn't clickable, and that once you get to more than one line, the line height gets messed up (the original problem) Thank you for your input though !